# Transform double value in Grails withCriteria

Tags: grails, transform

I am using Grails withCriteria to do some db query, but I have a problem with the return double value.
My criteria:

```
List data = Contract.withCriteria {
    projections{
        sum("value")
    }
}
```

(Property "value" in Contract class is Double type.)
The returned result is always displayed as 1.5437E8 instead of the exact value 154370000. How can I force Grails to return that exact value?
Thank you so much

Comment: What does your Contract domain class look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can try and override the tag used to display this field with `<g:formatNumber/>`

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html